# How to get high quality small file size screen recording on Mac?

Tags: mp4, h.264, screen-recording

The clips on http://hoverstat.es/ are the best examples of what I am after.

The spec are roughly:

- Format/Codec: mp4/h.264
- Dimension: 1280x720
- Audio: disabled
- File size: 1.5Mb for a 15 second clip (0.1Mb/s)
- Bitrate: ~750
- Quality: Near as sharp and crisp as screenshots; minimum visible loss/blur

I am using Quicktime to do screen recordings. Outputting file from MOV to MP4 with Handbrake (http://handbrake.fr/) on Mac. Managed to decrease file size significantly by setting bitrate to ~750 but the video quality is horrible. No where near clear and readable, not to mention crisp and sharp.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with AppGeeker, it compresses videos into a small file with a little loss of file quality.

http://www.appgeeker.com/how-to/convert-mp4-to-mov-mac.html

Make sure set the preferences to "High Quality" in its settings panel.